# Show that $f \colon \frac{1}{z-1} -\frac{1}{\bar{z}+1}$ is proper

Tags: complex-analysis, compactification

I need to prove that the map $$f \colon \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(1,0)\} \cup \{(-1,0)\} \to \Bbb R^2$$
$$f(z)= \frac{1}{z-1} -\frac{1}{\bar{z}+1}$$ extends to the one-point compactification $\Bbb S^2$ of $\Bbb R^2$
where we identified $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$ in the usual way.

> Since I have to define $f$ on $\infty, 1,-1$ in order to extend it to the one-point compactification (so not only on the infinity point I add), do I proceed as always? I.e. I'd try to show that $f$ is proper.

1) Assuming my approach is correct, how can I prove that such map is proper? Are there any clever way to do this? My approach is to try and prove that the preimage of a ball of radius $r<\infty$ is contained in a ball of radius $R<\infty$, but I'm not able to control its behaviour near the critical points.

2) I'm asked to compute its degree: since it's not surjective ($0$ is not hit) then it should be $0$ am I right?

Comment: **Two remarks:** **1.** It might be good to know what definition for the degree you have been given in your course (I guess it's not one that uses homology). Also, (**2.**) what is your definition for a 'proper' map? This is a topological term as far as I know, but you only seem to be wanting to show that the given map extends to the one-point compactification...

Comment: well, for (2), "my" definition of proper map is a map whose preimage of compacts are compacts. In my case I believe it's equivalent to the extensibility of such map to the compactification.

Comment: Yes, because you would get a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space. It just seemed strange to me, because the term 'proper' is only defined for continuous maps, anyways.

Comment: for (1) you are right, I noticed the exercise asks for the degree of the extension, so a map from the sphere to the sphere. So we can take the cohomology degree as a definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to show that the map extends, then you have to see if there is a limit for the case that the argument converges against $\pm 1$ or $\infty$.
   You can do this quite comfortably using simple instruments from real analysis, considering that convergence of a sequence against $\infty$ (in the one-point compactification) is equivalent to the absolute value converging against $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.
   Long story short:
   $$
   \forall \left(z_n\right)_n \in \left(\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}\right)^\mathbb{N} \left(
   \lim_n z_n = \infty \iff \lim_n |z_n| = \infty
   \right)
   $$
   Now, argue with the limit definition for continuity...
2. You will find out that the map *is* surjective; so even though the implication is right, you can't apply it.

Comment: I don't get why it should be surjective: $1/(z-1)-1/(\bar{z}+1)=0$ implies $z-\bar{z}=2$, i.e. $2i\Im(z)=2$

Comment: You have to argue with limits. Bring the fraction to a sum, then use the absolute value to find an upper bound that converges to $0$ for an argument converging against $\infty$. What you are trying to show with that equation is that the *current* function you have is onto the Riemann sphere, which isn't true.